# Google App Engine Datastore geospatial query api version number

Tags: java, google-app-engine, geospatial, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to search locations near by and I have a GeoPt field in the datastore kind.

I am trying to use the code mentioned here but do not seem to find the classes in the api..
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch?hl=en

I have these apis included in my gradle

```
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.8'
```

I do not seem to find the `StContainsFilter`  and `GeoRegion` (for circle) classes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, my project was added to the Geospatial Support for Datastore Alpha program but no API information was provided other than the above link.

Comment: how did you get an invite to the alpha program, if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: How to get invite for it ? as in the documentation it was provided as "Access to this feature is by invitation only."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the latest GAE SDK. 1.9.18 is quite old. I believe the current version is 1.9.27